# How is immobilized resolved in the context of Screech?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

> *Screech*
>
> The Strix emits an ear-splitting screech, rendering victims
>   unable to think or move and greatly assisting in a subsequent
>   feeding attempt.
>
> Dice Pool: Power + Finesse vs. victim’s Stamina + Composure
>
> If successful, the victim is stunned: She loses her next action,
>   and has only half her Defense until her next action. If the Strix
>   gains an exceptional success, or successfully uses this power
>   twice on the same victim in a scene, the victim is immobilized.

I used this against my players during combat, I was effectively able to immobilize all of them (or could have should I have chosen to), the problem I encountered is that Immobilize appears to have no end. Also unlike the description of the Immobilized tilt (which seems to not be in VtR2, but is in GMC) this is not a physical restraint.

How could my players have resolved this? Or what would bring it to an end? Suggestions on house rulings are welcome if no RAW exists.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the full description of the power, I would have done it like this:

- If successful, the victim is stunned: She loses her next action (Action 1) and until her next action (Action 2), she is at half defense.
- If the Strix gained an exceptional success **or** successfully used Screech on the victim while they were stunned (as in, during the period of Action 1 or 2), then the victim loses her next action (Action 1 or 2) and then is immobilized until their next action (Action 2 or 3).

So, the "immobilization" tilt replaces the "stunned" tilt, but the effect is otherwise the same — it lasts until the character's next action, which may be delayed by chaining things together.